# Python - Percentage (maths use) - Simplified x=a+15%

Tags: python, math, python-3.x, percentage, simplify

I have been using the following code in my programs to set the range of an axis so that the graph looks more aesthetically pleasing.

```
plot.set_ylim([0,a+(a*15/100)])
```

It is specifically this:

```
a+(a*15/100)
```

that i'm interested in.

Is there a function which exists which simplifies this?

The reason being is that when my graph is created in a for loop, and the value of a is the maximum value of a list (and so on) the whole thing starts to look messy.  E.g from:

```
a+(a*15/100)

max(listA[x])+(max(listA[x]))*15/100
```

Anyone aware of a simplification?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the *= operator

```
a = 100
a *= 1.15
print a # Returns 115
```

Beware that the *= operator may do different things for different types (i.e. strings and lists).

Answer (score 0):

I normally use for matplot stuff a variable calledn **ULIM** or something, (upper limit), so I  quickly can change it in one place which is not the call to *set_ylim*. Therefore, you can use

```
ULIM = a+(a*15/100)
plot.set_ylim([0,ULIM])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def limit(a, pct=15):
  pct = 1 + (pct/100.0)
  return a*pct

maxval = max(listA[x])
plot.set_ylim([0,limit(maxval)])
```